# Different behavior of MinMaxScaler() on similar range of series

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I am trying to understand Sklearn's MinMaxScaler's different behavior for the similar series.

I've 2 sets of series with 2 of each in it call it Normal and New. In each of the set, I want to reduce their scales relative to each other for the further processing. So, I am using one series' MinMaxScaler object to transform other series as in code below.

```
normal_ser = pd.read_csv(f"data1.csv")["normal"]

print("Series set 1")
print('\nNormal ser')
print(f'Normal max: {normal_ser.max()}, Normal min: {normal_ser.max()}')
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))
plt.plot(normal_ser)
plt.show()

print("Normal Ser histogram")
normal_ser.hist()
plt.show()

print('new ser')
new_ser = df2.read_csv("data2.csv")["new"]
print(f'New max: {new_ser.max()}, New min: {new_ser.max()}')
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))
plt.plot(new_ser)
plt.show()

print("New Ser histogram")
new_ser.hist()
plt.show()

print('Normal ser scaled')
# Scaling new series data based on the normal data series
mm_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
normal_ser_scaled = mm_scaler.fit_transform(normal_ser.values.reshape(-1, 1))
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))
plt.plot(normal_ser_scaled)
plt.show()

print('new ser scaled')
new_ser_scaled = mm_scaler.transform(new_ser.values.reshape(-1, 1))
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))
plt.plot(new_ser_scaled)
plt.show()
```

So for set1 of both normal and new series I am getting the output below.
[image: Set1]

Using the same code, I've another set of normal and new series and I am getting output as below.
[image: Set2]

In above pictures, we can see that the set1 and set2's normal and new have similar ranges. But the scaled values of both the new series has large difference. One is in -16.0 range and another is -2.5 range. Why is that happening? I understand there can be some difference but may not be this large.

Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like a typo: `Normal min: {normal_ser.max()`

Comment: Fitting a MinMaxScaler just means remembering the min and max value of a series. MinMaxScaler transform works like this: y = (x - min)/(max - min). The ranges of these series don't even intersect, so the outputs end up dissimilar.

Comment: But the ranges are nearby. Do you think it can have this big difference?

Comment: Yes. Just try to calculate it by hand.